# Temporary disable "viewchangeend" event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bing-maps

How can I temporary disable the `viewchangeend` event, change the view using `setView` method and re-enable the `viewchangeend` event again?

Here is a lighter version of what I'm doing now:

```
var mapEventsObjects = [];

/* Remove map events */
for ( var i = 0; i < mapEventsObjects.length; i++ ) {
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler( mapEventsObjects[i] );
}

/* Change the view */
map.setView({
    "zoom": zoom,
    "center": new Microsoft.Maps.Location( lat, long )
});

/* Add map events back */
var mapViewChangeEnd = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "viewchangeend", function (e) {
    console.log("viewChangeEnd Fired: ", e );
});

mapEventsObjects.push( mapViewChangeEnd );
```

What I expect is to see no *viewChangeEnd Fired* in the console, but it appears there not once but two times.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a gobal variable that is a simple Boolean. When you want to ignore the viewchangeend event, set the variable to true. Then in your event handler for the viewchangeend event you can do a simple check, if this variable is true, set the variable to false and leave the function. Here is a modified version of your code:

```
var mapEventsObjects = [], skipViewChangeEnd = false;

//Add view change end event to map.
var mapViewChangeEnd = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, "viewchangeend", function (e) {
    //Check to see if you want to skip this event once.
    if(skipViewChangeEnd){
        skipViewChangeEnd = false;
        console.log("viewChangeEnd skipped");
    }else{
        //Your logic for handling this event
        console.log("viewChangeEnd Fired: ", e );
    }
});

mapEventsObjects.push( mapViewChangeEnd );

skipViewChangeEnd = true;

/* Change the view */
map.setView({
    "zoom": zoom,
    "center": new Microsoft.Maps.Location( lat, long )
});
```

Comment: I need to temporary disable the events before calling `setView` and then re-enable it. Because of the Async nature of JS, if I set that variable to true, then call `setView` and set it back to false again, it will be false at the time `setView` is being invoked.

Comment: No it won't. It won't be set to false until the setView call has fired and the map has finished moved. I've actually used this method several times before.

Comment: You are never re-enabling the event. After calling `setView` you have to set `skipViewChangeEnd` to `true`, so it will continue working as normal. But if you do this, it will be set `true` before `setView` finishes, therefore letting the event fires again.

Comment: You only need to set it to true the next time you call setView. The skipViewChangedEnd variable should stay false until then. Your code sample only shows calling setView once.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up comments. I've solved the problem another way.